# How to handle SSL certificate in browser-mob proxy using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I need to handle the SSL certificate in browser-mob proxy so that secured connection can be established whenever URL starts with https. I tried many methods to handle the SSL certificate, but it is showing the unsecured connection.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import time
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


server = Server("/home/Downloads/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4-bin/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy(params={'trustAllServers':'true'})
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(proxy.proxy))
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/proxy', data = {'trustAllServers':'true'})
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions, 
desired_capabilities=capabilities)
proxy.new_har("test",options={'captureHeaders': True})
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
driver.close()
```

Comment: Please, add relevant tags.